# How to disable server cache in Jetty

Tags: java, caching, server, jetty

Jetty caches by default static resources like property files for performance reasons. For instance, some code like this:

```
public class FrontServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private final Properties routes = new Properties();

    @Override
    public void init()
        throws ServletException
    {
        try {
            this.routes.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("routes.properties"));
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

would continue working even after I delete the `routes.properties` file, because it would still be available from the cache, rather than from the disk. [The Eclipse Jetty plugin documentation](http://eclipse-jetty.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html) also mentions this: look for "Disable Server Cache".

Now, I'd like to disable this feature in development environments to avoid false positives. [The Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-extras.html) mentions that there is a init parameter called `maxCacheSize` that, if set to `0`, disables the cache. However, I tried it both as a context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.maxCacheSize</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and as a servlet init parameter:

```
<servlet>
    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.maxCacheSize</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

to no avail.

Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

The `routes.properties` file is still found even after I restart the Web server, and the Vagrant virtual machine it's running on. I should also mention that I'm using the [Maven Jetty plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin), thus launching the server with `mvn jetty:run`.

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to a server cache.

The `routes.properties` is loaded once, during Servlet Context Initialization, and used from then on out.

Only a destroy of the running context (ie: restart the web server) will cause it to call `FrontServlet.init()` again.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried restarting the Web server, and even the whole virtual machine, but still the properties file was found, despite being physically absent.